# define start to finish positions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a new "whack-a-mole" style game where the children have to hit the correct numbers in accordance to the question. So far it is going really well, I have a timer, count the right and wrong answers and when the game is started I have a number of divs called "characters" that appear in the container randomly at set times.

I have been given a theme of bubbles so they want me to make the "characters" start at the bottom and animate upwards. Any ideas how I would achieve this?

Here is the code that currently maps the divs to there positions in the canvas...

```
function moveRandom(id) {

var cPos = $('#container').offset();
var cHeight = $('#container').height();
var cWidth = $('#container').width();

var pad = parseInt($('#container').css('padding-top').replace('px', ''));

var bHeight = $('#' + id).height();
var bWidth = $('#' + id).width();

maxY = cPos.top + cHeight - bHeight - pad;
maxX = cPos.left + cWidth - bWidth - pad;

minY = cPos.top + pad;
minX = cPos.left + pad;

newY = randomFromTo(minY, maxY);
newX = randomFromTo(minX, maxX);

$('#' + id).css({
    top: newY,
    left: newX
}).fadeIn(1000, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#' + id).fadeOut(1000);
        window.cont++;
    }, 7000);
});
```

Here is my most recent fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part below actually set the CSS (and thus the position of your element).

```
$('#' + id).css({
    top: newY,
    left: newX }).fadeIn(1000, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#' + id).fadeOut(1000);
        window.cont++;
    }, 7000); });
```

You should add a function move who uses a movement variable. Small example:

```
function move(movement, id) {

$('#' + id).css({
    top: this.css('top') + movement.y,
    left: this.css('left') + movement.x
}).fadeIn(1000, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#' + id).fadeOut(1000);
        window.cont++;
    }, 7000);
});

}
```

Where in movement should be an object something the like of {x: 30, y: 0} which would result in a 30 pixels movement to the right. Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok thanks. I want them to move upwards though any idea how that would be acheived @Luigi van der pal

Comment: var movement = {x: 0, y: -5}

maybe you can set up a fiddle... so I can help further